# Finding the 'optimal distribution' with one unknown variable

Tags: distributions, optimal

I am trying to find the optimal distribution (of ingredients) with one unknown parameter (skillset).

Example, when baking a bread the ingredients are flour,salt,yeast and water. When I ask 100 bakers to bake a bread lets asume I get 100 different distributions for the ingredients (for example baker 1 used: 25% flour, 25% salt 25% yeast and 25% water). After rating the queality of the bread and inspecting the distribution of the ingredients I will get a pretty good idea of the average distribution used. However the skillset of the baker is probably more important then the exact distribution. And the skillset is unknown to me.

There are pretty hight correlations between the ingredients. Flour (.6) salt (-.2) etc and the rating of the bread. This leads me te believe that adding more flour and less salt is the 'secret' to baking the perfect bread even though a skilled baker probably made a 'better rated' bread with a less optimal distribution of ingredients.

My question: are there known solutions for finding the best distribution and if so, what are they called?

Comment: It's plausible--as you discuss--that the ingredient distribution is related to the skillset, in which case you simply cannot answer your question with these data, because you cannot distinguish the effects of skills from the effects of ingredient choice.

Comment: But why is there a significant correlation between 'more flour' and a better outcome no matter the skill. I am finding this correlation constantly on multiple retries of my experiment (the experiment is not about baking bread but this is an example that fits the problem perfectly). This leads me to believe that there is a secret formula along the lines of quality = baker skill + cross entryopy (baker distribution/perfect distribution). I tried the average distribution and then randomly changing small sections with a good result. It just seems extremely ineffecient to randomly try and recompute

Comment: If you control for baker skill, you can use methods like [response surface methodology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Response_surface_methodology) to try to figure out some optimum combination of inputs

Comment: Glen_b, thank you. This looks like the sort of thing I'm looking for!